# Windows network folders across routers

Tags: windows

**Case 1 (Three routers, not ok)**

Router1 WAN(Internet)
Router1 LAN: 10.0.0.1

Windows Server: 10.0.0.3

Router2 WAN: 10.0.0.2
Router2 LAN: 172.16.1.1

Router3 WAN: 172.16.1.2
Router3 LAN: 192.168.1.1

PC: 192.168.1.2

PC can ping 10.0.0.3 Windows Server, but cannot open network folders.

**Case 2 (Two routers, ok)**

Router1 WAN(Internet)
Router1 LAN: 10.0.0.1

Windows Server: 10.0.0.3

Router2 WAN: 10.0.0.2
Router2 LAN: 172.16.1.1

PC: 172.16.1.2

PC can open network folders.

**Question:**
Why case 1 not ok, but case 2 ok? Should I do some port mapping on case 1's router2 or router3?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Router3, internet ok, but network folders not ok. Find another router replace it, works!